# converter html em excel

Tags: php

Bom estou fazendo a conversão dessa forma:

```
$html = "
<table width='90%' border='1'>
   <tr style='background: #D7D7D7;'>
      <th>Título </th>
      <th>Título 2</th>
      <th>Título 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Dados 1</td>
      <td>Dados 2</td>
      <td>Dados 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Dados 4</td>
      <td>Dados 5</td>
      <td>Dados 6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Dados 7</td>
      <td>Dados 8</td>
      <td>Dados 9</td>
   </tr>
</table>
";

// Determina que o arquivo é uma planilha do Excel
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

// Força o download do arquivo
header("Content-type: application/force-download");

// Seta o nome do arquivo
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");

header("Pragma: no-cache");
// Imprime o conteúdo da nossa tabela no arquivo que será gerado
echo $html;
```

Porém estou enfrentando 2 problemas. 1° preciso salvar o arquivo no servidor ao invés de baixar ele, 2° Preciso fazer o CSS ser reconhecido.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar montar uma planilha utilizando o [formato oficial](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php), que nada mais é que um arquivo ZIP com os assets, XMLs e outros arquivos dentro.

Você pode montar este `.xlsx` na mão (uma loucura na minha humilde opinião) ou utilizando uma biblioteca como o [PHPSpreadSheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Um exemplo extraído da documentação:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

Comment: No seu exemplo você esta criando um arquivo xlsx com Hello World !. é possível mandar meu html para essa biblioteca?

Comment: Na verdade você vai precisar montar célula por célula a sua planilha. Da mesma maneira que você montou seu HTML... Ou seu HTML já vem pronto e você não tem os dados que precisa?

Comment: O meu html já vem pronto. Por isso estou tentando converter ele.

Comment: Aí você teria quer fazer um *scrapping* do seu HTML para extrair os dados e depois montar a planilha.